# Load apache camel routes at runtime

Tags: apache-camel, java-17, spring-boot-3

In the project , I've been dynamically loading Apache Camel routes during runtime.
Current environment includes `Spring 2.7.4, Apache Camel 3.18.0, and JDK 17`

```
private void fromFile(final Path filepath) throws Exception {
    final byte[] routeDefinitionBytes = Files.readAllBytes(filepath);
    final Resource resource = ResourceHelper.fromBytes(filepath.toString(), routeDefinitionBytes);
    final ExtendedCamelContext extendedCamelContext = camelContext.adapt(ExtendedCamelContext.class);
    extendedCamelContext.getRoutesLoader().loadRoutes(resource);
}
```

Now migrating project to utilize `Apache Camel 4.0.0-RC1`, `Spring Boot 3.1.1`, and continue to use `JDK 17`. The issue facing is that the adapt() method isn't available in the newer version of Apache Camel, rendering your existing code non-functional.

I'm seeking a viable solution that can allow me to continue reading route definitions from a file and inject them into an Apache Camel context at runtime in `Apache Camel 4.0.0-RC1`. Any recommendations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such a need, you can rely on the utility method [`PluginHelper#getRoutesLoader(CamelContext)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-support/latest/org/apache/camel/support/PluginHelper.html) but behind the scenes, the new logic is to call `getCamelContextExtension()` on the camel context to get the `ExtendedCamelContext`, then get the plugin that you want to use thanks to the method [`ExtendedCamelContext#getContextPlugin(Class)`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.camel/camel-api/latest/org/apache/camel/ExtendedCamelContext.html).

So your code would then be:

```
private void fromFile(final Path filepath) throws Exception {
    final byte[] routeDefinitionBytes = Files.readAllBytes(filepath);
    final Resource resource = ResourceHelper.fromBytes(
        filepath.toString(), routeDefinitionBytes
    );
    PluginHelper.getRoutesLoader(camelContext).loadRoutes(resource);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76809559/7733418 let me point out that after the `PluginHelp.getResourceLoader`, the camelContext needs to be started started, e.g.,
`camelContext.start();`.

Comment: This doesn't really look like an answer, more a comment. Please make it more explicit but highlighting the important part.

Comment: I did my best to reduce the impression of a comment. It still does not really seem like a full standalone answer according to [answer]. PLease review my edit, and [edit] yourself accordingly.